# Bootloader with graphics (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

I have written simple bootloader based on: http://www.viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php

```
[BITS 16]   ;16bit
[ORG 0x7C00]    ;offset

MOV AH, 0x00 ; change video mode
MOV AL, 0x13 ; 0x13
INT 0x10 ; interrupt
CALL DrawTenLines   ;lets draw
JMP $       ;hang it

DrawOneLine:
MOV CX, 0x00 ;x = 0

nextpixel:
MOV AH, 0x09 ;func number - WritePixelOnScreen [wiki]
MOV AL, 0x05 ;color - Magenta
MOV BH, 0x00 ;Page no
INT 0x10 ;Video interrupt - BIOS
CMP CX, 10 ;if (x == 10) {
JE exitfunc ;exit function } else {
JNE nextpixel ;next pixel }
ADD CX, 0x01 ;add one :D
exitfunc: ;exit :D
RET

DrawTenLines: ;draw some lines
MOV DX, 0x00 ;y = 0
CALL DrawOneLine
MOV DX, 0x01 ;y = 1
CALL DrawOneLine
MOV DX, 0x02 ;y = 2
CALL DrawOneLine
MOV DX, 0x03 ;y = 3
CALL DrawOneLine
MOV DX, 0x04 ;y = 4
CALL DrawOneLine
MOV DX, 0x05 ;y = 5
CALL DrawOneLine
RET

;Data

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;Fillers
DW 0xAA55           ;boot signature
```

But this doesn't work as expected - doesn't draw, only black screen and hangs (as expected).

Compiled with NASM, -f bin. Example from this site works. Tested in Virtualbox.

EDIT: Forgotten to change video mode - but still doesn't work.

EDIT 2: This code:
    [BITS 16]   ;16bit
    [ORG 0x7C00]    ;offset

```
MOV AH, 0x00
MOV AL, 0x13
INT 0x10
MOV AH, 0x09 ;WritePixelOnScreen [wiki]
MOV AL, 0x0F ;color - White
MOV BH, 0x00 ;page no. 
MOV CX, 1 ;x
MOV DX, 1 ;y
INT 0x10 ;interrupt
MOV CX, 2 ;x
MOV DX, 1 ;y
INT 0x10 ;interrupt
MOV CX, 3 ;x
MOV DX, 1 ;y
INT 0x10 ;interrupt
JMP $       ;hang

;Data

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;filler
DW 0xAA55           ;boot signature
```

Makes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXszE.png

Comment: BTW. Whats with the second part? Can you help me with that one, too?

Comment: could you add your completed code so I can replicate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in `DrawOneLine`. This line is never being executed:

```
ADD CX, 0x01 ;add one :D
```

Your looping code should look more like this:

```
CMP CX, 10 ;if (x == 10) {
JE exitfunc ;exit function } else {
ADD CX, 0x01 ;add one :D
JMP nextpixel ;next pixel }
```

I think your issue may be using the wrong video mode. You set the video mode to mode 0x13, and then you call `INT 0x10, AH=0x09`, which I believe is a text-mode function. IIRC, the screen data for mode 0x13 is located at 0xA000:0x0000, and you can write to it directly.

EDIT: I think `INT 0x10, AH=0x0C` is what you were trying to use, intead of `INT 0x10, AH=0x09`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I think these 2 lines:

```
MOV CX, [EAX] ;x
MOV DX, [EBX] ;y
```

should be:

```
MOV CX, AX ;x
MOV DX, BX ;y
```

(No square brackets, and use the lower 16 bits.)

Longer answer: I don't think the code is hanging where you think it is. I would expect it to be hanging due to these 2 lines:

```
MOV CX, [EAX] ;x
MOV DX, [EBX] ;y
```

Your code comments indicate that you understand C, so I will explain in those terms. The instructions:

```
MOV EAX, 0x00
MOV CX, [EAX]
```

are equivalent to:

```
unsigned int EAX = 0;
unsigned short CX;
CX = (unsigned short)(*EAX);
```

I might not have the casting correct. The point is that putting the brackets around EAX ("[EAX]") uses the contents of EAX as a pointer. I would expect your code to dereference a NULL pointer, which might be causing the hang.

**EDIT, per your update**

You are trying to write a pixel on the screen using this interrupt:

```
MOV AH, 0x09 ;func number - WritePixelOnScreen [wiki]
MOV AL, 0x05 ;color - Magenta
MOV BH, 0x00 ;Page no
INT 0x10 ;Video interrupt - BIOS
```

I don't see any coordinate parameters there. I looked up the int 10h functions and I find that AH=09h is ["write character and attribute at cursor position"](http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~ray/teaching/CA296/notes/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.html#int10h_09h) -- not what you want. Look at [AH=0Ch -- "change color for a single pixel"](http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~ray/teaching/CA296/notes/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.html#int10h_0Ch). That link has a short example demonstrating proper usage.

Comment: I replaced EAX with CX and EBX with DX and removed every single reference to EAX and EBX, but still not working

Comment: You may need to update the code in your question. I don't understand the corrections you have made, or if I do understand them, they're incorrect.

Comment: But @up has posted about this same problem.